# can't install vim-plug

Tags: neovim, plugin-vim-plug

how could I install vim-plug?

My config:

- Manjaro Linux - 22.0.0
- Kernel - Linux 5.15.76-1-MANJARO
- nvim - 0.8.0

So, there is a command (1) for linux with nvim users on vim-plug [git rero](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#neovim)

```bash
sh -c 'curl -fLo "${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}"/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
       https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim'
```

Expected behavior:

- After I inserted (1) in terminal, system would install that and I also would able to  to installing plugins

Real behavior:

- After I inserted (1) in terminal it seems that system just have downloaded this and nothing else, there is only:

```bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 83129  100 83129    0     0   105k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  105k
```

I can't use vim-plug in nvim config.

`Update:`
**There is no any problem. Check** [**this**](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3729#issuecomment-159039730).

Comment: Check if the file `$HOME/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim` exists. If it does, you've installed vim-plug. Why do you say "I can't use vim-plug"? What have you tried?

Comment: @3N4N, plug.vim file exists. I cant't use it, because when I write `:PlugInstall` an error message appear "`E492: Not an editor command: PlugInstall`".

Comment: Add the output of `:set rtp` to your question, please.

Comment: @3N4N, I have solved my problem in other way, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3729#issuecomment-159039730).

Answer from **noahfrederick:**

"Note that the `:PlugInstall` command will not be available until the autoload script is sourced, which occurs when you source it manually, or more usually, call one of the autoloaded functions, such as `plug#begin()` in your *init.vim*."

Huge thanks for help to [**3N4N**](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/16280/3n4n).